# How can I search for a string say "xyz" in the pixel value's of an image using c# or Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a challenge, where I need to find a particular string: example "XYZ" (this string has been encoded within the image).

Every pixel consists of ARGB and I have to check every pixel's Red color - if that, contains the required string (3 character string).

I have tried few things and I am able to read the values of a every pixel's red color value which returns an integer.

My issue is: How can I search for the occurrence of **that three character string** within every red pixel of an image?

Any suggestions would be really appreciated

Below is the code I am using to read the values of the pixel of an image.

```
     Bitmap img = new Bitmap("F:\\pam\\Wallpapers\\red.jpg");
           // MessageBox.Show("Image height:" + img.Height + "" + "Image width:" + img.Width);
          //  MessageBox.Show("Image found at"+img);
            for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
    {

     //   String mark1 = 
        Color pixel = img.GetPixel(i,j);
        pixel = Color.FromArgb(pixel.R);
    //    string a = Color.fr
       int nPixelR = pixel.R;
      //  string q = img.GetPixel(0, 0);
        //pixel.R 
      //  img.GetPixel(0, 0);

       string pixelColorStringValue =
                       pixel.R.ToString("D3") + " " +
                       pixel.G.ToString("D3") + " " +
                       pixel.B.ToString("D3") + ", ";

       switch (pixelColorStringValue)
       {
           case "255 255 255":
               {
                   // white pixel
                   break;
               }
           case "000 000 000":
               {
                   // black pixel
                   break;
               }
           case "255 000 000":
               {
                   // black pixel
                   break;
               }
       }
        MessageBox.Show("pixel value" + pixel);
        if (pixel.Equals("a"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Keyword Found:");
            //  **Store pixel here in a array or list or whatever** 
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you like strings more than numbers?

Comment: Do you mean the red values, in order, will encode a string where the red value corresponds to an ascii character?

Comment: If you know the font used and size on the picture in advance the easiest method would be using the GDI+ to render all letters that could display on the picture and then find all occurrence of the actual pattern of the letter A on the image, then letter B and so on. keep the location it was found and then you know from left to right what are the letters you found.

Comment: What is that `switch()` block doing? `Color.FromArgb(pixel.R);` shouldn't even compile. Please: read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: @hometoast What's wrong with `Color.FromArgb(pixel.R)` ? Except that it makes no sense, it will compile.

Comment: @ hometoast: well it's like I am supposed to check every red pixel of that image .. if it has that string attached to it..how can i search for a string in that =red pixel's value is the my issue..

Comment: You don't need a switch whatsoever. just use `if(pixel.R == whatever && pixel.G == somethingElse)` etc

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: aye. you're right. forgot the encoding argb as an int option... you're right though -- it makes no sense.
Gdroid: But you're not saying HOW it is encoded. You're missing a large piece of information to answer the question

Comment: @hometoast : It will be encoded using matlab script..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if string was encoded into image from-top-to-bottom, then you should swap `for` loops.

```
    private void Search()
    {
        SearchKeywordInRedPixels("xyz", "F:\\pam\\Wallpapers\\red.jpg");
    }

    private void SearchKeywordInRedPixels(string keyword, string imagePath)
    {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(imagePath);
        byte[] keywordBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyword);

        Point firstMatchingBytePos = Point.Empty;
        int currentByteIndex = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
            {
                Color pixel = image.GetPixel(x, y);

                if (pixel.R == keywordBytes[currentByteIndex])
                {
                    if (currentByteIndex == 0)
                        firstMatchingBytePos = new Point(x, y);

                    if (currentByteIndex == keyword.Length - 1)
                    {
                        KeywordFound(keyword, firstMatchingBytePos);
                        currentByteIndex = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentByteIndex++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    currentByteIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void KeywordFound(string keyword, Point pos)
    {
        string msg = String.Concat("Keyword ", keyword, "found at ", pos);
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use `string strPix = (char)pixel.R + (char)pixel.G + (char)pixel.B;` and then just check if that matches your search string?

Edit:
Or better yet: Convert your XYZ to RGB and just compare to the pixel? Something like:

```
var searchColor = Color.FromRgb('X', 'Y', 'Z');
```

Then compare it to your pixel.

Comment: It should be `'X', 'Y, 'Z'`, no cast necessary, `char` instead of `string`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the 2d array and look for X. When you find it, check if value to the right is Y. If it is, check if value two steps to the right is Z. If it is, you have found it.